# Is it possible to remove weak Ciphers or edit registry settings on Web Applications hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, encryption, registry, azure-function-app

Our Security team reported use of weak cipher even though we are using TLS 1.2 configuration on our web app. I would like to get clarity about weak cipher suite and how we can remove weak ciphers from our TLS 1.2 configuration as we can see all weak cipher details on the scan site. As Azure functions\web app is a managed service, is there a way to disable them or is it possible to modify registry settings for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure web apps, there is currently no support for removing the cipher suite from a request. It is not possible to make any configuration changes in the Registry settings for web applications as seen in this document - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#writing-to-registry.

You can only set your TLS settings to 1.2 for high security and a request is negotiated with the client to use whatever cipher they both have, so by default a client will typically use one of the ones that's not weak. There has been feedback from many Azure customers for a feature request to remove/disable insecure ciphers but so far only RC4 has been disabled across the service as seen - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7091994-disable-insecure-ciphers-in-azure-websites?page=2&per_page=20, although Microsoft is constantly reviewing cipher suites.

For now, there are 3 possible ways to remove weak ciphers:

1. App Service Environment - This gives you access to set your own ciphers though Azure Resource Manager - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-custom-settings#change-tls-cipher-suite-order. I reproduced this and found out that it is possible to set your own ciphers or change the cipher suite order by modifying the clusterSettings in https://resources.azure.com/.
2. Using Azure FrontDoor – You can configure a minimum TLS version in Azure Front Door in the custom domain HTTPS settings via Azure portal. Once you configure TLS1.2, only the following strong cipher suites are supported:
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
   You can find more information on this here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq#tls-configuration.
3. Using Application Gateway – This lets you specify a central TLS policy that's suited to organizational security requirements and helps to meet compliance requirements. The TLS policy includes control of the TLS protocol version as well as the cipher suites and the order in which ciphers are used during a TLS handshake as seen in this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ssl-policy-overview.

Comment: Thank you Regina for providing the workarounds !